# Selected Option from URL Parameter and Show Element

Tags: jquery, html, parameters, element

When I try to send parameter via URL below, the hidden element did not visible.

https://codepen.io/jafaris-mustafa/pen/dyoooVJ?checkSpeed=form-speed-100

and if without the parameter the first option did not visible.

https://codepen.io/jafaris-mustafa/pen/dyoooVJ

Thank you in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".form-select-wrap>div").hide();  
  $("#select-speed").change(function() {    
    var currentSelection = $('#select-speed :selected').val();    
    var search = $(this).val();    
    $(".form-select-wrap>div").hide()     $('.' + search).show();     
  })


  function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null
  }
  var val = getURLParameter('checkSpeed');
  $('#select-speed').val(val); //  assign URL param to select field

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-speed" name="checkSpeed">
  <option>Select Speed</option>
  <option value="form-speed-30">30</option>
  <option value="form-speed-100">100</option>
  <option value="form-speed-300">300</option>
</select>

<section class="form-select-wrap">
  <div class="form-speed-30">30mbps only</div>
  <div class="form-speed-100">100mbps only</div>
  <div class="form-speed-300">300mbps only</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Given the code and URL in your question, your example works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wjf85tqz/. Please check your console for errors. Also note that online JS editors use frames, so providing a URL parameter in the parent window will not work as the JS frame won't see it.

Comment: Just add `.change()` on `$('#select-speed').val(val).change();` to execute the event `onChange` setted in the `ready function`

Answer (score 0):

This one should works, thanks to Roy Bogado.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".form-select-wrap>div").hide();
    $("#select-speed").change(function(){
        var currentSelection = $('#select-speed :selected').val();
        var search = $(this).val();
        $(".form-select-wrap>div").hide()
        $('.'+search).show();    
    })


function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
var val = getURLParameter('checkSpeed');
  
  if (val){
    $('#select-speed').val(val).change(); //  assign URL param to select field
}
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-speed" name="checkSpeed">
  <option>Select Speed</option>
  <option value="form-speed-30">30</option>
  <option value="form-speed-100">100</option>
  <option value="form-speed-300">300</option>
</select>

<section class="form-select-wrap">
  <div class="form-speed-30">30mbps only</div>
  <div class="form-speed-100">100mbps only</div>
  <div class="form-speed-300">300mbps only</div>
</section>
```